# Git - Break a piece of code off from Master and make it a Branch

Tags: git

I have a project I've been working on for quite some time, but have never released.  I have a feature I started working on (multiplayer support) and then I realized I do not want to include in version 1.0.

I recently started controlling my source-code with git. I committed my entire source code as "initial version commit" on master.

I'm using the branch-for-each-new-feature structure that is popular.

I would like to remove the multiplayer code from "master" and put it into a branch called "multiplayer".  This way I can make the rest of the changes I need for v1.0, release v1.0 without any multiplayer code, and then after v1.0 is released, I can rebase my multiplayer branch, start working on it, and have it be included in v2.0.

This is  a bit of a strange problem because the issue arose because I started using git to version control a project halfway through.  I haven't seen anything on the net proposing a way to address this.

I have a solution in mind, but it seems bad.  I will post it below as an answer, but not accept it.  Hopefully someone will be able to provide a better answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git checkout -b multiplayer` (This will create a branch, called multiplayer, for your feature  based on your master)
3. Few possibilities:

   - If you have clear commits of this feature you can revert them: **git
     revert _your_hash_**
   - If you have clear commits of this feature you can remove them from
     the history by rebasing, you will have to push force after : **git
     rebase HEAD~x -i** x is the number of commits behind you want to check,
     you can delete a line to remove it, -i is interactive.
   - You should do a cleanup commit and remove your code on the master.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I have come up with, but don't like:

1. Save all of the relevant source files (i.e. anything that references multiplayer) somewhere else.
2. On my master branch, go through all of my source files and remove all multiplayer code.
3. Commit this on master branch with the message "breaking off the unfinished multiplayer code into separate branch"
4. Create and switch to a new feature branch named multiplayer
5. Copy in the the source files that I saved in step 1.
6. Commit the "changes" to multiplayer branch.

I think this would work, but I feel like there's probably an easier way to do this.  Maybe not, since the nature of the problem is a little strange.

Answer (score 2):

Almost, but you don't need the step of copying the code someplace else.

- from master `git branch multiplayer` you now have a separate branch with all the code in it, but you are still on master.
- delete the code you don't want
- commit.
- rebase multiplayer not master when you want.